# USB-C SBU1/2: Leave unconnected or ground through ESD protection diode?

Tags: usb, esd, usb-c

I have a circuit where the USB-C receptacle breaks out SBU1 and SBU2, but I don't plan to use these pins.  Initially, I planned to leave them unconnected as shown below.

[image: usb-c connector with SBU1 and SBU2 unconnected]

However, I wonder whether it would be smarter to connect these two pins to ground through ESD protection diodes.  It won't protect *my* circuit from anything, since I don't use those lines, but would it potentially protect the host PC at the other end?

What I'm thinking is that if SBU1 or SBU2 were to pick up ESD on my board it could transmit it backwards through the cable into the host PC and cause damage there.

So, should I do ESD diodes or just leave them unconnected?

Comment: Thank you.  These two comments answer my question.  I will leave the SBU pins unconnected.

Comment: It's unlikely that you would have ESD on those pins, because the shell and shield will conduct any ESD to ground or chassis ground. 

One problem you could get with putting a diode on the SBU1 or SBU2 is ground loop issues. Leave them unconnected